# Get parent taxonomy term id when on child taxonomy template page in wordpress cpt

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom post type with a taxonomy "section" and I have a template page with a query loop to display a list of categories with thumbnails. I only want to show the child categories of the current parent taxonomy and want to be ably to get the ID of the parent category when on a child page.

I have currently set the parent as id 40 in my code but need this to be dynamic. How would dynamically change the 40 to the current parent id?

This is the code I have in my taxonomy template page.

```
<?php
      $terms  = get_terms( [
          'taxonomy'      => 'section',
          'parent'        => 40,
          'hide_empty'    => true,
          'relationship'  => [
              'id' => 'categories_to_posts',
              'to' => get_the_ID(), // You can pass object ID or full object
          ],
      ] );
      if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term->term_id );
        $term_name = $term->name;
        $url = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'kte_sec_thumbnail_image', true );
          echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $url ) . '">';
           $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
           echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term_name . '</a>';
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can understand that you want to show current parent taxonomy's child terms on parent taxonomy page. So use this code to achieve your functionality..

```
<?php 
$term123 = get_queried_object();
$slug=$term123->slug;
$parent_id  =$term123->parent;
$child_id=$term123->term_id;


$taxonomy_name ='section';
$termchildren  = get_term_children(  $child_id, $taxonomy_name  );
echo "<ul>";
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
?>
  <?php if ($term->parent == $child_id) { ?>

    <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
  <?php } 

  ?>

<?php } 
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, thats worked. When I first pasted the code into my template I got no result, but I checked using var_dump to debug and the $parent_id returned was correctly returned the the parent ID. I have then used this with my original code using the $parent_id to replace the id of 40 I had in my original example and now my template works correctly. Your help is much appreciated.